# Comparison of close data sets

Tags: clustering, estimation, dataset, multilevel-analysis, pattern-recognition

I'm studying around **100 sets** of temperature (**$N_{sample}=500$**), which depends $4$ explicative variables such as power or speed.

The dependency is always the same in each set, but sometimes the mean and the variance is different.

- I would like to **group similar sets together** and study each group separately: find a multiple regression model for each group.
- Then I would like to **classify future sets** I will discover in one of those groups.

I don't know if it concerns clusterisation or pattern recognition or maybe something else. But I have no idea of how to do classifiy/compare my sets, except comparing the mean and the variance one by one.

Does anybody have advices or suggestions?

Here is an example of 3 sets:
[image: Temperature vs power]
[image: Temperature vs speed]

Comment: When you you say "study each group" are you thinking about something like a multiple regression model, or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: Yes exactly. At the beginning I did a multiple regression to estimate the tempetaure. But then I realised my model was "an average model" over all sets, so not accurate enough. 
So I  wanted to classify my several sets of temperature before doing my regression so I can have one model by set.

Comment: But couldn't you simply include dummies for each set, and dummy$\times$variable interactions and thereby fit different hyperplanes to each set within a single model?

Comment: I don't know much about dummy variable. But if I understood correctly I will have 100 dummy variable and 100 regression models written in one form, wouldn't I?
What I would like is having one regression model for each group, not for each set.

Comment: Sorry, when you used the word 'set' there I thought that meant 'group'. Read 'group' for 'set' in what I said before. So in your diagrams, this will add two [dummy variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29) that give three different intercepts, and if you want different coefficients for each as well (different slopes), then the dummy x variable interactions will triple the total number of coefficients.

Comment: Dummy variables are the subject of numerous questions here on CV, and are a standard way to deal with the multiple group issue in regression problems. Some packages will construct and fit dummy variables automatically (such as R); you just have to tell them you have a group variable ('factor' in R).

Comment: When you say "set" is there anything associating the set across the different groups (like being taken at the same time, say)?

Comment: Oh okay. I think I will use dummy variables as you said but only once I get my groups, which is my initial problem.

Each set corresponds to a machine. Some machines seem to have the same behaviour regarding their temperature(same y-intercept,same mean...), some don't and I'm hoping to discover something about the resons of those similarity/differences once I form my groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try to model the sets, for example using a multivariate Gaussian distribution, or a Gaussian Mixture Model.

Then use [Kullback Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) measure to *compare the models*, and you should be able to use any distance-based clustering algorithm.

Comment: Do I have to truncate the interval of the explicative variables to study my temperature in the same field before doing the modelization with Gaussian mixture?
Is it more efficient that k-neighbour clusterisation?

Comment: There is no "k-neighbor clusterisation" that I know of. Do you mean k-means or knn *classification* (supervised)? Either way, you are then comparing apples and oranges: this is a method to compare two data sets(!) which k-means cannot do.
You can then e.g. run hierarchical clustering to build a dendrogram of your data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a clustering problem, but instead of individual observations you have entire datasets.

What could be possible here is for each data set calculate some features, e.g. min, max, 25th and 75th percentiles, mean, median, std, linear regression coefficients, etc. And then try to use some clustering techniques to group them. It's just an idea, not sure how it's going to work, but this is what I'd do in this case.

Once you learned the classes of your data set, you want to classify new data sets - and this is a classification problem. Here you use same set of feature (maybe new ones as well) to train your classifier, and then use it to classify new datasets.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the suggestion by Alexey Grigorev:   You could build some multilevel model, on level one, for each individual situation ("data set") a linear regression model, such as
$$
   y_{ij}= \alpha_j + \beta_j x_{ij} + \sigma_j \epsilon_{ij}
$$
where data sets are indexed with $j$ and observationhs within each data set is indexed by $i$.  Then on the second level, that is for the coefficients $\alpha_j, \beta_j, \sigma_j$ you can have some mixture prior.  That will probably need MCMC for estimation.  One paper which seems to do something like this is here:  http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sks/research/papers/sahudeybranco.pdf